# Change the value of a custom attribute for an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a document with two thumbnail images (front and rear such as a bank check). I can zoom in the front thumbnail image by displaying in the zoom a square a part of the front image from  the original (large) image. Everything works so far. 
Clicking on the front image, swaps it with the rear and I should be able to display the zoom of the rear. However, this doesn't work. I believe the zoomingRear() attribute should be modified and supplied with a value to the custom attribute OR the zooming() needs to refresh somehow to display the other image. Any ideas how?

My images with sources from sessions:

```
<img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="zoom_mw" onclick="this.src = this.src == rear() 
? front() : rear();" src='<%= Session("ImageThumbnailPathFront")%>' 
data-zoom-image='<%= Session("ImagePathFront")%>' width="500" height="250"  />
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args)
    {
     zooming()
    }
    function front() {    

        return onImg = '<%= Session("ImageThumbnailPathFront")%>'; 

    }
    function rear() {    

        return offImg = '<%= Session("ImageThumbnailPathRear")%>'; 
        zoomingRear()
     }
    function zooming() {   

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#zoom_mw").elevateZoom({ scrollZoom: true });
        });
    }
    function zoomingRear() {    // <-- Problematic function

        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.querySelector(data-zoom-image='<%= Session("ImagePathRear")%>').elevateZoom({ scrollZoom: true });
           // document.getElementById(
        });
    }
    function getElementByAttribute(attr, value, root) {
        root = root || document.body;
        if(root.hasAttribute(attr) && root.getAttribute(attr) == value) {
            return root;
        }
        var children = root.children, 
            element;
        for(var i = children.length; i--; ) {
            element = getElementByAttribute(attr, value, children[i]);
            if(element) {
                return element;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling zoomingRear() from your onclick, but that's way after your page has been loaded, so no point using $(document).ready() inside zoomingRear(). Just try to remove that and leave the code like:

```
function zoomingRear() { 
    document.querySelector(data-zoom-image='<%= Session("ImagePathRear")%>').elevateZoom({ scrollZoom: true });
}
```